# Android/samsung galaxy S emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there a way, to try my project on a samsung galaxy emulator, or something like that?

My project work on HTC Legend, but its crashes on that device. How i can set up a samsung galaxy s on android/eclipse?

I set up a W800/854 2.2 AVD but it work.. but on the samsung phone it was a crash..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The odd thing with Galaxy S is the presence of two external storages. This can not be emulated in AVD. More over current Android SDK lacks support for two storages. At least this was the issue with my own application on Galaxy S.

Comment: +1, interesting. Can you tell us what kind of problems did you have?

Comment: any note on this? i work with sd card too.. can u tell me more about it?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() references to build-in external storage. There is no way in API to get reference to SD card installed by user. The only way for the time being is to ask user, e.g. in preferences. I can't tell exactly what was wrong, but I've got two crash reports from Galaxy S, before I have redesigned that part of code for some other reason.